# JSON.NET slow deserialization on first use on Android only

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, json.net

I'm building a Xamarin Forms app, and using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize my json.

Only on android(works fast on iOS), deserializing takes a long time(10-12 seconds) to deserialize. The second time, on the exact same json, is very fast.

A couple people on the web suggested they fixed the same issue by downgrading to json.net 8.0.3 however it doesn't appear this supports .net standard which I am using. I have tried 9.0.1 and 10.0.2 and have this problem.

Comment: report it here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happens the first time you Deserialize an object.
You can try to deserialize a little object at App's startup... then you should have faster deserialization after it.
Let me know

Comment: I tried Deserializing an empty object on start up in a background thread on the android main activity, hoping that it would be finished by the time it got to the home page but it doesn't appear to have helped at all.